# HDD S.M.A.R.T. Power On Count more than Power On Hours

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, smart

My HDD is only 5 months old and it is already failing. Currently I am backing up my data but I realize when I check for the S.M.A.R.T. info, my power on count reaches 2,926 count but my power on hours is only 1,578. I keep refreshing it and noticed while copying files, the speed frequently drops to 0 kb/s and then back to normal. The power on count keep increasing for around 3 count per 10 seconds.

What is wrong with my computer? Is this only the HDD fault or are there any problem with my PSU? Should I replace something?

[image: CrystalDiskInfo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this seems to be clearly a HDD fault. Don't see why this would be related to PSU.

Your C5 (197 dez) and C6 (198 dez) attributes indicate that your disk is failing, because raw data is not zero anymore.

Please see
http://help.argusmonitor.com/SMARTmonitoring.html

section 'Category Caution' and Backblaze data for more detailed explanations.

This could also be the reason for the fast increasing power on count (when OS or firmware does a HDD reset on reading sectors which have failures).

You already did the right thing, backup your data at once.